# Camera fulcrum visible in solid mode cutting off objects

Tags: 3d-view, camera

[image]

I seem to have enabled some camera fulcrum option, this is only visible in wireframe and solid modes. Can anyone tell me how to disable it as it's clipping my objects, also is there a hotkey combo i've maybe hit by mistake?

Comment: Clear the clipping region Alt+B (or on the menu: View> View Regions> Clipping Regions)

Comment: @susu YES I had created a clipping region for an earlier render! Thanks so much. As this has been asked before I'll delete this question. Actually its going to be ref to the answer you pointed me too.

Comment: No, don't delete the question. It might help others find the information they need. Duplicates are very useful.

Comment: For future searchers, OP used the term _fulcrum_ but almost certainly intended _frustum_. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum